# How would you say "I can't help but wonder whether..." in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, syntax

I am trying to translate the lyrics of the Eric Bogle's song "The Green Fields of France" to Latin. The first two verses of the last stanza of the song are:

> And I can't help but wonder, oh Willie McBride,
> do all those who lie here know why they died?

How would you say that in Latin? A literal translation from English might be:

> Et ego non possum mihi adiuvare praeter me ipsum rogare, o Willie McBride,
> num omnes ii qui iacent hic sciant cur mortui sint?

However, I guess that's not proper Latin. In Croatian, you would say:

> A ja ne mogu da se ne zapitam, o Willie McBride,
> znaju li svi oni koji ovdje leže zašto su umrli?

Which would be literally translated as:

> Et ego non possum ut me non rogem, o Willie McBride,
> num omnes ii qui iacent hic sciant cur mortui sint?

But I guess that's not proper Latin either.

So, how would you say that in Latin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My first inclination is that [*quin*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dquin) is the right word for the job. Though it has a lot of meanings (including "why not," after verbs of hesitation, and even to mean "qui non"), there are several examples from Cicero's letters that seem close to your target sentence:

> **Facere non possum quin** in singulas res meritaque tua tibi gratias agam, sed mehercules facio cum pudore. (Cicero, *Epistulae ad Familiares*, 10.24)

> tamen **facere non possum quin** cottidie ad te mittam ut tuas accipiam. (Cicero, *Epistulae ad Atticum*, 12.27)

So, one possible translation with this construction might be:

> Neque facere possum quin admirer, o Guilelme Fili Brigittae, an omnes hic iacentes sciant quem ad finem mortui sint.

(I'm a bit dubious about this usage of *admiror...an*, but perhaps that's material for a different question. I can't find any Latin precedent for *se rogare*, which seems to be the favored idiom in many other languages.)

Comment: The second quote seems to be, Cic. ad Atticum 12.27.2.